# jQuery Tools Alternatives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I'm using [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools) for most of my sites but it seems that it ceases development. I have no choice but to look for individual jQuery plugins equivalent to that of jQuery Tools.

I'm looking for suggestions on the best alternatives for:

1. jQuery Tools **Tabs + Toolbox.History**
2. jQuery Tools **Overlay + Toolbox.Expose**
3. jQuery Tools **Tooltip**
4. jQuery Tools **Validator**

Thanks.

Comment: Oops meant to vote as Not Constructive

Answer (score 12):

**jQuery Tools** has become a disaster... I think Tero got in way over his head trying to rival **jQuery UI** and just no time to support the product.  I tried it for a while and his methods are certainly unique.  He turned the jQuery tag-line of *"write less, do more"* completely upside down and in my opinion, only does himself and the jQuery community a disservice.  He rarely posts in his own forums and has not released an update in over six months despite more and more incompatibilities with the ever updating **jQuery**.

I really like [**prettyPhoto**](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) for the Overlay Lightbox effect.  It's well supported and dynamically re-sizes itself to properly & automatically fit any content.  It supports titles and captions as well as an optional mini thumbnail gallery inside of the lightbox itself.

There are also six skins (themes) included which are based on popular site designs.

There's nothing wrong with Fancybox at all, but **prettyPhoto** has a lot more cool features enabled right out of the box.  Literally only takes a few minutes to set it up to function like the demos.

It also plays nice with other plugins.  I use [**jCarousel**](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) to display my thumbnails and prettyPhoto to zoom in on them when clicked.

jCarousel takes a bit more CSS fiddling to look they way you want but both of these plugins are fully customizable.  If you know your CSS, you should have no trouble duplicating the exact look of your old jQuery Tools applications.

**EDIT:**

I agree with others on the following...

[**qTip2**](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/) is an excellent ToolTips plugin and I think [**the jQuery Validation Plugin**](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) is really the **only** way to do jQuery form validation.

**EDIT 2:**

[**FancyBox 2**](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) is great and more solid than prettyPhoto in my opinion.  There are animated opening and closing effects which you don't get with prettyPhoto.  If you don't need the mini thumbnail slideshow within the lightbox, I prefer FancyBox 2 over prettyPhoto.

**jCarousel** has a major bug in `circular wrap` that the developer has acknowledged yet fails to fix.  You cannot wrap around.  Even the online demos are broken.  [**jCarousel Lite**](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) does not have any issues at all with circular wrapping.

Excellent, VERY popular and solid, non-carousel style slide-show plugins with transition effects include [**Nivo Slider**](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) and [**Cycle**](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

**EDIT 3:**

I've recently discovered [**Tooltipster**](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/) and now heavily favor it over **qTip2**.

Answer (score 3):

1. [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)
2. Depending on how you're using the overlay, [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) or [blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)
3. Depending on how fancy you want it to look, [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/), [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/), [clueTip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/), or [jQuery UI tooltip](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip) (still in dev)
4. The [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: I'm a NO No to jQuery UI. Can Fancybox overlay dynamically created new DOM content? Regarding qTip, I'm still waiting for the new version to come out. Thanks for the blockui info.

Comment: @bloggerious: I assume you don't like the look&feel of jQuery UI tabs? You can make your own skins for them, [create & style your own tabs](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-tabs/), or use any of the other [bajillion tab plugins out there](http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-user-interface-plugins-jquery-plugins/ultimate-collection-of-jquery-tabs/).

Answer (score 0):

For tooltips also look at Poshy Tip http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/