# Alternatives to jQuery Tools Scrollable?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've been working for some time with jQuery Tools, mostly Tabs. And for the past few weeks I also used their Scroll solution, but now it doesn't fit anymore and I cannot get it work in the circumstances I'm working in.

So I'm just asking here in hope that I will get some clue, if there are any alternatives to jQuery Tools's Scrollable ( [Scroll](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html) ) ?

Comment: I imagine you could probably fix your current code. Maybe make that your question (with the relevant code/markup/[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)).

Comment: I would need a database, so jsfiddle it's out of question. Perhaps I could upload it on the server for everyone to see. But I'm looking for some alternatives too, maybe there is something better out there that I can use.

Comment: I suppose this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561409/jquery-tools-alternatives

Comment: [jQuery Cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/).

Comment: There's the super-fancy: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/

Comment: I'm using it for content, not images. You can see an example of it here: http://codecanyon.net/item/secure-login-system/full_screen_preview/1379963.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found something quite good, but it isn't free, check [this](http://codecanyon.net/item/touchcarousel-jquery-content-scroller-and-slider/896401) out. So if anyone has the same question I had this plugin can be quite helpful, and it's touch enabled too. Since jQuery Tools hasn't been updated in some time and jQuery UI doesn't have a defined method for scrollable like Tools, I think this plugin is the best option, at least for me.