# Multiple buttons with an overlay attached, can't find open overlay

Tags: jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

I am trying to use the jQuery tools overlay, and it works very nicely when there is a static set of buttons that launch the overlay.

However, when the buttons that are linking to the overlay are recreated, the overlay seems to get orphaned and I can't see why. I can't close it, and I can't even find a reference to it by going through the DOM with each().

I've seen some solutions which involve triggering a click, but for one thing this seems like an inelegant solution, and for another it causes the overlay to flicker before closing when I try it. I'd like to understand the reason why this doesn't work, as well as a good solution, can anyone help?

HTML

```
<div id="container">

</div>
<button class='modalLaunch' rel='#modal'>
    Uncontained launch button
</button>
<div id="modal">
    Modal
    <button id="rebuildContainer">Rebuild container</button>
</div>
```

​
Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#modal").hide();

    var rebuildContainer = function() {
        $("#container").html("<button class='modalLaunch' rel='#modal'>Contained launch button 1</button><br><button class='modalLaunch' rel='#modal'>Contained launch button 2</button>");           

        var triggers = $(".modalLaunch").overlay({
            mask: {
                color: '#bbbbee',
                loadSpeed: 200,
                opacity: 0.9
            },
            closeOnClick: true,
            load: false
        });
    }

    $("#rebuildContainer").click(function() {
        console.log("rebuilding buttons inside the container div");

        $(".modalLaunch").each(function() {

            var o = $(this).overlay();
            if (o) {
                console.log("there is an overlay associated with this button");
                if (o.isOpened()) {
                    // I would expect this to be true once each time the handler is called
                    console.log("the overlay associated with this button is open");
                }
            }
        });

        $(".modalLaunch").overlay().close();
        rebuildContainer();
    });

    rebuildContainer();
});
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/EveryoneMustWin/hjJtc/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking this, I've read this question [jQuery Tools Alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561409/jquery-tools-alternatives) and decided that it's probably best to abandon jQuery Tools. The forums on their site don't even let you start a new thread!