# What's a good library to replace jQuery tools?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

[jQuery tools](http://jquerytools.org/) of late has been heavily neglected. Some great updates have been made on the [github](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools), but it's not enough. As of jQuery 1.9, the [overlay plugin is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923301/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined-jquery-tools). It's a shame because I love how much control the library gives you, both over javascript and styling.

For me jQuery UI and jQuery mobile are not options, styling them is a nightmare, and using a theme roller to emulate a stylesheet I've already written is redundant and annoying.

I use the [range input slider](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/rangeinput/index.html), [scrollable](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scrollable/index.html), and [overlay](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/index.html) on a lot of projects. Does anyone have any recommendations for libraries that are staying current with jQuery? Thanks.

Edit - possible duplicate. My search didn't find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561409/jquery-tools-alternatives/5958269#5958269).

Comment: Short answer: [ANY other library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5958269/594235).

Comment: jQueryUI+plugins? This question doesn't look like a good fit for SO, asking "which library is the best at" is almost never constructive.

Comment: I've used jquery UI, but never themeroller.  For my purposes, I was always able to style what I needed by hand.

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery 1.8? Is jQuery tools definitely suspended or do they just need time to catch up?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It was a very specific question - what alternative to jQuery tools offers the same functionalities (the ones I listed) as jQuery tools

Comment: check out this link and site http://jster.net/category/ui-frameworks

Comment: @inorganik See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157319/where-to-ask-initial-architecture-library-questions

Comment: @Moak I am for the time being, but that means using deprecated functions of jQuery, and not using the best available jQuery out there. Plus the touch support on jQuery tools is bad.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum this is not a "what's the best library" it's a "what's my alternative" question. I will bet that many others would benefit from an answer. Too many people on S.O. spend all their time policing it rather than being constructive... why is that?

Comment: jQuery Tools has been spiraling the drain for nearly three years now.  When its own developer doesn't care anymore, why would anyone else?

Comment: Policing SO is a noble thing.  It's the only way to maintain a very high quality repository of Q & A.

Comment: @Sparky agreed... but it feels nitpicky in this case. I believe an answer here would benefit a lot of people

Comment: This question will spark debate and will probably get closed for the "not constructive" reason.

Comment: @sparky if anything it's a duplicate. My search didn't find the existing question though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561409/jquery-tools-alternatives/5958269#5958269

Comment: Yes, it's probably a duplicate and older questions get closed too.

Comment: @inorganik "What's a good library for X?" is non-constructive, and you know this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit already had this conversation with another commenter- I was asking for an alternative, not "a good library for X." If it's not constructive, why was it voted up twice and starred?

Comment: Lots of questions earn up-votes before getting closed.  That's because it's not a bad question... it's just not a good fit for SO.

Comment: @inorganik Your question title is "what is a good library for..." Take this up on http://meta.stackoverflow.com if you disagree with site policy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit shouldn't this have been closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561409/jquery-tools-alternatives/5958269#5958269 Just be consistent, that's all I ask.

Comment: @Sparky Shouldn't you have closed the duplicate as well for the same reason? I saw you edited it on May 11, '11 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561409/jquery-tools-alternatives/5958269#5958269 - it remains open.

Comment: @inorganik Yes. Thanks for pointing that one out; I have now cast my vote. Please remember that **there are 4.7m questions on Stack Overflow** and, although I _am_ your god, I do not have time in the day to look through all of them. This website is a group effort.

Comment: Would you feel any better at all about this if your question had been closed as an _"exact duplicate (of a "not constructive")"_ rather than  _"not constructive"_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for humoring me. :) Personally I find that question very useful, and I'm glad it's there.

Comment: @inorganik The community votes to close things as appropriate as they come across them. In the past, different content was permitted here. Old content gets closed as people come across it, but new content gets seen on the front page, so gets closed sooner.

Comment: @sparky Just exact duplicate… look- I understand that you guys don't find it adhere's to a blurry set of rules - but fact remains it's useful to people. Clearly, you control this site so do what you like. I would just say, look to the spirit of S.O. rather than the letter of the law when moderating it. Thx for the discussion.

Comment: Simply "being useful" to people is not enough... and **everyone** controls this site, including yourself as you continue to earn rep.   See the http://meta.stackoverflow.com site if you'd like to discuss this further.

Comment: @inorganik I could post my mum's recipe for tomato soup and it would be _useful_ to many people; that does not automatically mean it belongs here. Stack Overflow is not a catch-all for everything that might possibly be _useful_ in the entire world. It has a stricter set of criteria than that. In this case, it is you who holds a fundamental misunderstanding of Stack Overflow's spirit, my friend.

Comment: I too would like an answer to this - jQ Tools is dead and I need a replacement - I have NO IDEA which libraries offer similar functionality. Why the Hell would SO nuke this question when it's so valuable to a lot of us who got stuck on a library which is now dead?